# Crash - calling onFragmentCreated after onDestory() was called on parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash, fragmentstatepageradapter

I got some crash trace from `Crashlytics` service and I need some help to understand what cause them.

I use the next flow :

I have my main `GeneralActivity` and inside that `Activity` I lunch a fragment that uses `MyMainFragment` and he uses `ViewPager` to display pages, each page is called `MyPage` and he extend `BaseFragment` .
Basically what I getting is a fragment with some pages to scroll using the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Sometimes I see users get crash because the main Activity `BaseActivity` calls `onDestroy()`. My question is why after calling `onDestory` it never get into the the `dispose()` in `MyPage` method but it enters into `onFragmentCreated`.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.myApp.GeneralActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3565)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3584)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
com.myApp.setAdapter (HackersProtected:32)
com.myApp.MyPage.onFragmentCreated (HackersProtected:165)
com.myApp.BaseFragment.onViewCreated (HackersProtected:105)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (HackersProtected:925)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (HackersProtected:1088)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (HackersProtected:1070)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (HackersProtected:1861)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated (HackersProtected:1474)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (HackersProtected:931)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (HackersProtected:1088)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (HackersProtected:1070)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchReallyStop (HackersProtected:1888)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop (HackersProtected:787)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop (HackersProtected:764)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy (HackersProtected:322)
com.myApp.BaseActivity.onDestroy (HackersProtected:122)
android.app.Activity.performDestroy (Activity.java:434)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Are you calling your method after super.onDestroy()?

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit, what you mean by "your method" ?

Comment: Well you haven't posted any code but usually you get that error when you try to do anything in onDestroy method after the super is called.